# custom short url for joomla 3.X

Tags: php, joomla, short-url

I am working on joomla 3.X and i have create component custom.

Here is its link how the custom component page is open : http://joomlavogueteamdemo.com.bh-in-7.webhostbox.net/petitions-new/view-petitions/ireland/LuasOn

Here Petition-new is component name
View-Petitions is Petition View

We want its short url like: http://joomlavogueteamdemo.com.bh-in-7.webhostbox.net/petitions-new/ireland/LuasOn

Here we have attached our router.php code also.

```
    function petitionsBuildRoute(&$query)
{  

  print_r($query); 
  if($query['Itemid'] != '487'){
       $segments = array();   
       if (isset($query['view']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['view'];
                unset($query['view']);
       }
       if (isset($query['id']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['id'];
                unset($query['id']);
       }
       if (isset($query['pid']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['pid'];
                unset($query['pid']);
       };

       if (isset($query['name']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['name'];
                unset($query['name']);
       };

       return $segments;
  }else{
      $segments = array();   
      return $segments;
  }
}


function petitionsParseRoute($segments)
{     
       $vars = array();
       $app = JFactory::getApplication();
       $menu = $app->getMenu();
       $item = $menu->getActive();


        if($segments[0] == 'Ireland'){          
            $vars['view'] = 'Ireland';                                                   
            $vars['name'] = $segments[1];           
            //name to get id
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `#__petitions_signataires` WHERE `ref` = '$segments[1]'";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $row = $db->loadRow();
            $pid= $row[0];                                                      
            $vars['pid'] = (int) $pid;  

            return $vars;       
        }


       switch($item->query['view'])
       {              
               case 'categories':
                       $vars['view'] = 'categories';
                       break;
               case 'category_petition':
                        if($segments[0] == 'detail_petition'){
                           $vars['view'] = 'detail_petition';
                           $id = $segments[1];
                           $vars['id'] = (int) $id ;
                        }elseif($segments[0] == 'Ireland'){
                            $vars['view'] = 'Ireland';                                                   
                            $vars['name'] = $segments[1];

                            //name to get id
                            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                            $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `#__petitions_signataires` WHERE `ref` = '$segments[1]'";
                            $db->setQuery($query);
                            $row = $db->loadRow();
                            $pid= $row[0];                                                      
                            $vars['pid'] = (int) $pid;
                        }
                       break;
               case 'article':
                       //$vars['view'] = 'article';
                       $id = $segments[0];
                       $vars['pid'] = (int) $id[0];
                       $vars['latestnews'] = 'latest';
                       $vars['detailslink'] = 'link';                      
                       break;
                case 'com_petitions':
                       $vars['view'] = 'id';
                       $id = $segments[0];
                       $vars['id'] = $id[0];                                       
                       break;                      
       }
       return $vars;
}
```

So please help us here to resolve this single issue in my job.

Regards,
Urjit